# Spring Social + Spring MVC + Maven

Tags: facebook, spring, spring-mvc, spring-social

Since this morning i'm trying to make a simple mvc + spring social maven application (without using spring boot or gradel).

i'm missing the configuration files, i dont know how to do so,i allready tried the few examples on internet but without any issue.

please anyway can provide me with a simple working application/article ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one that we found to work and is simple enough to understand.

http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/adding-social-sign-in-to-a-spring-mvc-web-application-configuration/

The site has multiple categories of Spring Social as well http://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-social-tutorial/

If you still have issues, paste your code and error in the question to help figure them out.

Comment: the project is not working neither ....i put the app-id and app-secret by when i try to connect to facebook there is no answer from the server.
otherwise the application is too big i just need something the less possible configuration to integrate spring social with mvc.

Comment: The answer provided is best that can be done based on the question. If you having issues you need to raise new questions advising of the details so that community can find you fixes.

Comment: No worries. If the answer helped feel free to accept it or up vote it :)